# Does Appcelerator Titanium Apps run independently?

Tags: titanium

Is Titanium like adobe air and .net and all... i mean does it require some things installed first so that it can run... Or can it be used for making standalone apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although **Yes**, the Titanium Runtime needs to be installed on the client computer, its probably misleading to say that it distributes like Adobe AIR.

With Adobe AIR, the run-time is installed and then your system can launch proprietary **.air** files. Titanium packages applications into the native app wrappers (**.app** on osx for instance).

When packaging your application you can choose "Network" or "Bundled" which allows users who have downloaded your app to download the Titanium Runtime from the Titanium Network automatically, or include it bundled within your application (thus no internet connection is required and the user doesn't need to even know they are running a Titanium App)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appcelerator_Titanium

Answer (score 0):

No, It looks like it has to be installed.